# I try to get the result of the a twig variable

Tags: variables, twig

I try to get the result of the order history status in Opencart with this code snippet. At the `{{ status }}1` the variable result is `'New Order'`, but at `{{ status }}2` the variable don't show any result. What have I done wrong?

```
{% set status = "" %}
{% for history in histories %}
    {% set status = history.status %}   
    {{ status }}1
    {% if status == 'New Order' %}
        {{ status }}2
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue without any success in [this twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/rxqgn1) can you share more detail/code?

Comment: More code at https://twigfiddle.com/rxqgn1/2

Comment: https://twigfiddle.com/rxqgn1/3